# How to allow all user to see an uploaded image VB.NET winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a social media app for my family. I have added: logins, comments, likes etc, but the only images a user can see are the ones they posted. How do I make it that all the users can see all the posts. Thanks, Bye

```vb
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form1.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Me.Visible = False
        Me.Enabled = False
        Form1.PictureBox1.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

So it just uploads the picture to the form1.picturebox, so how do I save it and upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving images to the local machine then obviously the app will only be able to see those images when running on the local machine. Any instance of the app running on a different machine will not be able to see them. If you want all machines to see all images then you need all images saved to one place that all machines have access to. Where that is is up to you. It might be a NAS drive on your local network if that's the only place you'll run the app. It might be a web server or cloud storage service for universal access. The specifics are up to you.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I upload the file to OneDrive they should be  able to see it right?

Comment: If the application connects to OneDrive then it doesn't matter where the application is because any connected machine can access OneDrive. Stop thinking about the specific scenario and start thinking about the principle. If you understand principles then you can apply them to many different scenarios and answer questions like that yourself.